# ¿Cómo puedo agregar un scroll al contenido del modal para visualizarlo de manera responsive?

Tags: html, css, scroll, responsive

Buenos días, tengo la siguiente página : [Cuadernillo Latinbook](http://latinbooksint.com/cuadernillos/index.html) que muestra una serie de cuadernillos, al hacer click en la tapa de los libros se despliega un modal con una información en común y su respectiva imagen. Sucede que al intentar ajustar con `@media queries`, en resoluciones de dispositivos, al hacer touch, se despliega la info pero es demasiado larga, hay manera de que uno pueda desplazarse por esa info independientemente de la página? algo así como un scroll o un "ver más"? Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te sugiero que hagas que que la ventana modal `.contenidoventana` mida la altura de la pantalla o un poco menos con la propiedad `height: 100vh` luego le agregas la propiedad `overflow-y: scroll` para poderte desplazar de forma vertical por el texto si este es muy largo.

Comment: Genio, es exactamente lo que precisaba, funcionó a la perfección